# How can I display a list of users currently online without using membership

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to display a list of users currently logged on to a website.  At the moment it displays the number of users logged on but I would like to show who is logged on as well?

**Online.aspx:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="panel">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Online Users</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <asp:GridView
                            ID="gvOnlineUsers"
                            runat="server"
                            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                            GridLines="None"
                            CssClass="table table-bordered table-hover">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="country_name" HeaderText="Country" SortExpression="country_name"></asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="userCount" HeaderText="Users" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="userCount"></asp:BoundField>
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**When user logs on:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        txtUsername.Focus();
        GetAuthenticationInfo();

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Request.Browser.Cookies)
            {
                /*Check if the cookies with name UM_LOGIN exists on user's machine.*/
                if (Request.Cookies["UM_LOGIN"] != null)
                {
                    string strQuery = "EXEC sp_um_getCredentials '" + Request.Cookies["UM_LOGIN"]["username"].ToString() + "','" + Request.Cookies["UM_LOGIN"]["password"].ToString() + "'";
                    DataSet ds = DataControl.GetDataSet(strQuery);
                    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["lockStatus"].ToString() == "LOCKED")
                        {
                            Toastr.ShowToast("Your account is locked due to invalid login attempts and will be unlocked after " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["unlockTimeRemaining"].ToString() + " or else you may contact your administrator to unlock the account.", "Account Locked", Toastr.Type.Error);
                        }
                        else if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["lockStatus"].ToString() == "INVALID")
                        {
                            int intAttemptsLeft = 0;
                            intAttemptsLeft = maxLoginAttempts - int.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["failed_attempts"].ToString());
                            Toastr.ShowToast("Password is invalid. You are left with " + intAttemptsLeft + " more attempts.", "Error", Toastr.Type.Error);
                        }
                        else if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["lockStatus"].ToString() == "VALID")
                        {
                            loginStatus = 1;
                            Session["loginStatus"] = loginStatus;
                            Session["userId"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["user_id_pk"].ToString();
                            Session["firstName"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["first_name"].ToString();
                            Session["middleName"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["middle_name"].ToString();
                            Session["lastName"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["last_name"].ToString();
                            Session["userName"] = txtUsername.Text.Trim();
                            Session["password"] = txtPassword.Text.Trim();
                            Session["userRole"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["user_role"].ToString();

                            if (bool.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["user_status"].ToString()).Equals(true))
                            {
                                /*Store the log date and time*/
                                string strQueryLog = "EXEC sp_um_addLog " + Int32.Parse(Session["userId"].ToString());
                                DataControl.ExecuteNonQuery(strQueryLog);
                                Response.Redirect(ResolveUrl("default.aspx"), false);
                            }
                            else
                                Toastr.ShowToast("Your account is suspended", "", Toastr.Type.Error);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toastr.ShowToast("Invalid Username or Password", "", Toastr.Type.Error);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Toastr.ShowToast(ex.Message, "Error", Toastr.Type.Error);
    }
    finally { }
}

public void GetAuthenticationInfo()
{
    try
    {
        string strQuery = "SELECT remember_me, forgot_password, throttle_auth, maximum_attempts, company_name FROM tbl_settings";
        ds = DataControl.GetDataSet(strQuery);
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            if (bool.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["remember_me"].ToString()) == true)
            {
                divRememberMe.Visible = true;
                rememberMe = true;
            }
            else
            {
                divRememberMe.Visible = false;
                rememberMe = false;
            }
            if (bool.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["forgot_password"].ToString()) == true)
            {
                divForgotPassword.Visible = true;
                forgotPassword = true;
            }
            else
            {
                divForgotPassword.Visible = false;
                forgotPassword = false;
            }
            maxLoginAttempts = Int32.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["maximum_attempts"].ToString());
            Session["maxLoginAttempts"] = maxLoginAttempts;

            strCompanyName = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["company_name"].ToString();
            Session["companyName"] = strCompanyName;
            lblCompanyName.Text = strCompanyName;
        }
        else
        {
            //
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Toastr.ShowToast(ex.Message, "Error", Toastr.Type.Error);
    }
    finally { }
}

protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (cbRememberMe.Checked && rememberMe == true)
        {
            if (Request.Browser.Cookies)
            {
                Response.Cookies["UM_LOGIN"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(360);
                Response.Cookies["UM_LOGIN"]["username"] = txtUsername.Text.Trim();
                Response.Cookies["UM_LOGIN"]["password"] = txtPassword.Text.Trim();
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Cookies["UM_LOGIN"]["username"] = txtUsername.Text.Trim();
                Response.Cookies["UM_LOGIN"]["password"] = txtPassword.Text.Trim();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            /*Clean the cookie UM_LOGIN.*/
            Response.Cookies["UM_LOGIN"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
        }
        string strQuery = "EXEC sp_um_getCredentials '" + txtUsername.Text.Trim() + "','" + txtPassword.Text.Trim() + "'";
        DataSet ds = DataControl.GetDataSet(strQuery);
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            /*Check whether the user account is locked or unlocked due to invalid login attempts OR valid OR invalid.*/
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["lockStatus"].ToString() == "LOCKED")
            {
                Toastr.ShowToast("Your accounts is locked due to invalid login attempts and will be unlocked after " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["unlockTimeRemaining"].ToString() + " or else you may contact your administrator to unlock the account.", "Account Locked", Toastr.Type.Error);
            }
            else if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["lockStatus"].ToString() == "INVALID")
            {
                int intAttemptsLeft = 0;
                intAttemptsLeft = maxLoginAttempts - int.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["failed_attempts"].ToString());
                Toastr.ShowToast("Password is invalid. You are left with " + intAttemptsLeft + " more attempts.", "Error", Toastr.Type.Error);
            }
            else if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["lockStatus"].ToString() == "VALID")
            {
                loginStatus = 1;
                Session["loginStatus"] = loginStatus;
                Session["userId"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["user_id_pk"].ToString();
                Session["firstName"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["first_name"].ToString();
                Session["middleName"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["middle_name"].ToString();
                Session["lastName"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["last_name"].ToString();
                Session["userName"] = txtUsername.Text.Trim();
                Session["password"] = txtPassword.Text.Trim();
                Session["userRole"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["user_role"].ToString();

                /*Check whether the user is active or not.*/
                if (bool.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["user_status"].ToString()) == true)
                {
                    string strQueryLog = "EXEC sp_um_addLog " + Int32.Parse(Session["userId"].ToString());
                    DataControl.ExecuteNonQuery(strQueryLog);
                    Response.Redirect(ResolveUrl("default.aspx"), false);
                }
                else
                {
                    Toastr.ShowToast("Your account is inactive, contact your administrator to activate the account.", "Account Suspended", Toastr.Type.Error);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Toastr.ShowToast("Invalid username or password.", "", Toastr.Type.Error);
        }
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Toastr.ShowToast(ex.Message, "Error", Toastr.Type.Error);
    }
    finally { }
}
```

Then in my **Global.asax:**

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Application["OnlineUsers"] = 0;
}

void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Application.Lock();
    Application["OnlineUsers"] = (int)Application["OnlineUsers"] + 1;
    Application.UnLock();
    Session.Timeout = 8;
}

void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Application.Lock();
    Application["OnlineUsers"] = (int)Application["OnlineUsers"] - 1;
    Application.UnLock();
}
```

So basically I would like display the users that are currently logged on in a `Gridview`

**UPDATE**

**Code Behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (Session["userRole"] != null || Session["userRole"].ToString() != "")
        {
            if (Session["userRole"].ToString().Equals("Admin"))
            {
                getOnlineUsers();
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect(ResolveUrl("~/eh/401.aspx"), false);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Toastr.ShowToast(ex.Message, "Error", Toastr.Type.Error);
    }
}
public void getOnlineUsers()
{
    try
    {
        string strQuery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_um_user WHERE user_id_pk = '" + Session["userId"].ToString() + "'";
        ds = DataControl.GetDataSet(strQuery);
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            gvOnlineUsers.DataSource = ds;
            gvOnlineUsers.DataBind();

            gvOnlineUsers.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
            gvOnlineUsers.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
        }
        else
        {
            ds.Dispose();
            gvOnlineUsers.DataSource = ds;
            gvOnlineUsers.DataBind();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Toastr.ShowToast(ex.Message, "Error", Toastr.Type.Error);
    }
    finally
    {
        //ds.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is exactly your problem ? - Ok you take this code from a sample and probably you do not understand what it does... Actually this is not accurate if you use web form or if the session ends fails.. maybe in case you not have inProc session. To solve your issue you need a database access and write there the infos. For better result you even need a javascript part to check every few seconds if the page is still on

Comment: I am trying to display the user names that are currently logged in on the website. I have edited my question with the code behind but doesn't display the current user logged on.  There are also no error messages.

Comment: you need to write some code and save  them to a database.

Comment: Can't I just take the current session of a logged on user and display it in a gridview?

Comment: This code use static variables to save them, this static are per application, so if you host it on a web garden you never see the actually users (and you lose this variables on every restart of the pool). This is a very old sample and I do not think that works correct at all. `Application[] ` is for compatible reasons with legacy asp, avoid it.